# How to update code when emulating Cordova app on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cordova

I have a Cordova project which I have opened with Xcode and then emulate from there. Xcode performs a git checkout of the project to a new folder and runs the code from there. However when I run the emulator, it seems to open and older version of my project because it includes a JS debugger which I deleted a long time ago.

When I look at the code in Xcode, it looks correct, but the emulator still runs the old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With cordova 3.X you are not supposed to work with xcode

Even if you are working with xcode, you have to run the `cordova prepare ios` command each time you change something.

You can create a script (in xcode select the project, go to build phases, click the + button, and new run script phase). It should be over the copy www phase

The code you need is:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/:/usr/local/bin
cordova prepare ios
```

EDIT: On Xcode 7 you don't need to add the PATH line, just `cordova prepare ios`

EDIT2:
On Xcode 8 I was getting cordova command not found, I think it uses it's own node version instead of the installed one. 
In case you have this problem then add Cordova path to your PATH.

As now I use nvm to handle node versions, the path I provided on my answer no longer works for my case.

Best thing to get the path is to  type `which cordova` in a terminal window, you'll get the Cordova path, something like: `/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/cordova`. 
Add that path without the cordova part to your build script before the cordova prepare ios, something like

`PATH=/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/:$PATH && cordova prepare ios`